# Phonegap: unable to override AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to limit the use of my Phonegap app to tablets only.
Reading [this page](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/) it seems to be possible via config.xml file.

In my config.xml file I made this changes:

1. Added: `xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
2. Added

   `<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
       <supports-screens 
           android:smallScreens="false"
           android:normalScreens="false"
           android:largeScreens="true"
           android:xlargeScreens="true"
           android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
   </gap:config-file>`

When I build the app, I can't see changes on the AndroidManifest.xml.
Where is my error? This procedure should works both with local build and remote build using  build.phonegap.com?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some hours I understand what happen: the gap:config-file works fine only if you use the PhoneGap Build (build.phonegap.com). After that I used android-apktool to get the AndroidManifest.xml from the generated .apk and I see my configuration.

Comment: You can also see the changes (and lack thereof) in the android/androidmanifest.xml file that's local to Phonegap. Did you ever find a way to alter the config file without having to do remote builds?